# Can I read an MQTT signal directly in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I am still finding docker compose a little confusing, I was wandering if I could read an MQTT value straight from the docker-compose.yml (not from a container), something like this but it doesn't work:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mqtt-subscriber:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./mqtt-subscriber/Dockerfile
    environment:
          - MQTT_BROKER_HOST="127.0.0.1"
          - MQTT_BROKER_PORT=1883
          - MQTT_TOPIC="POWER_STATE"
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: unless-stopped

  container1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./container1/Dockerfile
    network_mode: "host" 
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Also if I could create a function that once i recieve for example a 1 then shutdown all available containers, which in this examples are mqtt-subscriber and container1, and once it gets back to 0 turn them on (or should this be in a shell file or just separately in a container). So in a way the docker-compose is in charge of controlling all of the containers.

I have done my reaseach on this and some places it says that I can do it and some doesn't so I am confused help please!

I have tried the above code but it doesn't work, I have also tried reading the mqtt in a container which worked but I could not shut down the container itself unless its forceful with a terminal command but I don't want that.

Comment: Basically, you cannot do it using docker-compose itself. Docker Compose itself does not have the capability to directly read MQTT signals or control container operations based on MQTT messages. so you would need a container that listens to the MQTT topic and controls the other containers based on the received message. for example, in python there is a library named `docker` for this purpose.

Comment: oh okay! Thank you so much Benyamin, I thought it was possible I will then update the code to have it work within the container! Thank you! :)